# Instrumentation-based logging framewok for Java

Tags: java, logging, bytecode, instrumentation

I am trying to track down an issue in one of my Java projects and I am currently facing the possibility of having to manually add a *lot* of logging statements to a whole bunch of methods. As you can probably understand, I am not very fond of that idea:

- Most of those methods are performance-critical and I'd rather not add logging when it's not needed, even if it's something as lightweight as [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/index.html).
- In some cases I'd like to log the operation of classes from the Java library. While the OpenJDK source code is available, I am *not* going to provide my own Java library version just for this.
- I am interested in logging specific code paths under specific conditions. While I could probably centralize the logging applicability checks, I still foresee *unforeseen* refactoring in my future, should I need to modify the conditions.
- Adding logging statements *en-mass* requires a *lot* of work and time, which I'd rather use more productively.

Considering the existence of bytecode manipulation libraries, such as [Javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) and [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/), I was hoping that there might be a logging framework that would take the grunt work out of my hands.

Since I am mainly interested in logging method call arguments and return values under specific conditions, is there an instrumentation-based logging framework for Java that would allow me to do this? Preferably something somewhat more modern and a little less awkward than [Java agents](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/04/24/add-logging-at-class-load-time-with-instrumentation.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logging is the "hello world" of aspect-oriented programming.

If you're already a Spring user, you'll be able to write a single aspect class to log what you want and then weave it declaratively into all the objects that need it.

Spring has its own AOP implementation; it also supports AspectJ.

You can use AspectJ without Spring if that's your preference.

Comment: +1 AOP seems like a possible solution, one that I had considered before. I was, though, hoping for something a bit more specialized that would involve a minimum amount of effort on my behalf...

Comment: One class and some configuration to weave it in - how much less were you hoping for?

Answer (score 0):

Try this open source tool: http://code.google.com/p/perfspy/. It is a runtime logging, performance monitoring and code inspecting tool. It uses ApsectJ to weave around your application code at runtime, and logs the execution time of every method and its input parameters and values. It has a UI application, in which you can view the method invocations and their input and return values as trees. With it, you can spot performance bottlenecks and understand complex code flow.